# How to add new user in ubuntu core in sudoer file?

Tags: users, ubuntu-core, accounts

I'm having issue adding a new user to ubuntu core.

I use

```
sudo adduser --extrausers USERNAME
```

and successfully created a user but I cannot run any `sudo` command using that account.

```
$ sudo mkdir
[sudo] password for switchadmin:
switchadmin is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

Comment: Try and use visudo and follow the instructions there. Not sure if this works tho with core.

Comment: Or add the user to the sudo group: `sudo adduser USERNAME sudo`